# Linq to XML - Trying to print the Infinity symbol

Tags: c#, html, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using Linq to XML for some HTML output files.  I need to place the infinity symbol (`&#8734;`) in the code on output in some table cells.  I am creating an XElement like this

```
var table = new XElement("table",
            new XElement("tr",
                new XElement("td", "&#8734;")
            )
        );
```

var document = new XDocument(table);
document.Save(myFile);

and when the file is saved I am not seeing `&#8734;`, instead I see `&amp;#8734`.  How do I prevent this translation from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ to XML is doing the right thing - it's assuming that when you give it a string as content, that's the content you want to see. It's doing escaping for you. You really don't want to have to escape every `<`, `>` and `&` yourself.

What you need to do is give it the *actual content you want* - which is the infinity symbol. So try this:

```
var table = new XElement("table",
            new XElement("tr",
                new XElement("td", "\u8734")
            )
        );
```

That may well end up not coming out as an entity in the output file, just the encoded character - but that *should* be okay, so long as you don't have encoding issues.

EDIT: I've just checked, and the infinity symbol is actually U+221E, so you want "\u221e" instead. I can't actually see what U+8734 is meant to be... it may not be defined in Unicode at the moment.

Comment: For what it's worth, in LINQPad, instead of an infinity symbol, I see a Chinese character that may or may not come through when I paste it here: 蜴

Comment: @Joel: Yup, I've just checked and infinity is U+221E. Will edit.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this today and let you know how it goes.